# Why does Driving distance of pgRouting return disconnected results?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I am trying the driving distance function of pgRouting 2.0 beta, with an extract of OSM data.
The problem I have is illustrated on the following image :

[image]

On this picture i try to get all the ways accessible in 5 min from the downtown of the small city. For this purpose, I use the driving distance function. Clearly, the result is not ok : ways that should be returned are not, ways that shouldn't are (and far away from the area).

I'm pretty sure it's a problem during the creation of the topology, so I've tried various tool to import data and create the topology :

- osm2postgis, osmosis + pgr_createTopology function of pgRouting
- osm2po

With exactly the same kind of problem each time.

I've changed the tolerance of disconnected edge of the pgr_createTopology function and tried a large range of values, without success.

I haven't much experience in GIS, PostGIS and pgrouting.

I'm using PostGIS 9.2 + pgRouting 2.0 beta.

Comment: Can you run a shortest path query with a result that looks OK?

Comment: No, i get a result with a similar problem (ways disconnected)

Comment: Then your topology is probably created wrong, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `pgr_createTopology`, then the "snapping tolerance" is essential to have the same unit as your geometry. There are 2 cases:

1. Your projection is in "degree", then a value must be much smaller than 1, for example 0.00001
2. Or your projection in in "meter", then the value might 1 for example.

Comment: It seems that openstreetmap projection is in degrees. I've tried both 0.000001 and 1 for the "snapping tolerance" with no change in the error. The path is still composed by disconnected edges.

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling pgr_drivingdistance and then using id2 (the "edge id") to join back to your edge table?

If so, the pgr_drivingdistance function actually currently has a bug which causes this 'edge id' to not represent the actual path taken to get to that node. see https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/203

There's currently an open pull request to fix the issue (https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/pull/204). You can try pulling down this branch, re-building and re-installing, and see if it fixes your issue